# Excel VBA: Custom Function that finds the cumulative sum values in a Column based on Cumulative Value

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-columns, cumulative-sum

[image]

Hi,

I just started with Excel VBA and I'm working on a little project with cumulative data. The data in column1 i.e. A is static. I'm looking for a way to find the cumulative value (Output as Column B and E) based on the value of i using VBA.

How can I translate this operation to VBA?

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with formulas assuming your value for `i` is stored somewhere on the sheet

```
=SUM(OFFSET(E2,0,0,$B$1 + 1,1))
```

---

Where `B1 = i` and `Column E` is the range to sum

[image]